# Problem with Persian strings to URL address

Tags: php

my english is not good. sorry.

this is ok:

```
<?php 
$category = "music";
$subcategory = "pop";
echo "<a href=\"localhost/$category/$subcategory\"> Pop Music </a>";
//url output: localhost/music/pop 
?>
```

this is ok:

```
<?php 
$category = "music";
$subcategory = "پاپ";
echo "<a href=\"localhost/$category/$subcategory\"> Pop Music </a>";
//url output: localhost/music/پاپ
?>
```

my problem:

```
<?php 
$category = "موسیقی";
$subcategory = "پاپ";
echo "<a href=\"localhost/$category/$subcategory\"> Pop Music </a>";
//url output: localhost/موسیقی/پاپ
//It should be like this : localhost/پاپ/موسیقی
?>
```

It should be like this : localhost/پاپ/موسیقی

Comment: Can't reproduce it's working [here](https://3v4l.org/YqYf8)

Comment: @Jerson Sorry. I edited my questions. My problem is that two Persian words come together

Answer (score 1):

in mixing rtl with ltr font language this is happened. your code have not any problem.in show just different view but actually its work.
To be sure, you can var_dump() output and see the result.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my questions. My problem is that two Persian words come together

Comment: my answer is same again. you can test it.

Comment: thanks, but displacement is not just in appearance. It's really wrong and it does not work. see this [link](https://3v4l.org/3k4kW)